# Screen to SVG world coordinates are wrong even after creating SVG Point

Tags: javascript, svg, transform

I am trying to draw a path along mouse like in below snippet. It works, but the coordinates after applying transform are completely wrong. When you drag, you can see path added

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('.container');
var mousedown = false;
var svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
var path = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'path');
svg.appendChild(path);
var points = [];

var boundingBox = svg.getBoundingClientRect();

var toSVGPath = function(points) {
  var SVGPath = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var prefix = (i == 0) ? 'M' : 'L';
    SVGPath += prefix + points[i].x + ' ' + points[i].y + ' ';
  }
  return SVGPath;
};

svg.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  mousedown = true;
});

svg.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  if(mousedown) {
    var point = svg.createSVGPoint();
    point.x = event.clientX - boundingBox.left;
    point.y = event.clientY - boundingBox.top;
    var t = point.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
    points.push(t);
    path.setAttribute('d', toSVGPath(points));
  }
});

svg.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  mousedown = false;
});
```

```html
<svg class="container" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;height:100%;width:100%;-ms-transform:scale(1,-1);-webkit-transform:scale(1,-1);-moz-transform:scale(1,-1);-o-transform:scale(1,-1);transform:scale(1,-1);-ms-transform-origin:0, 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0, 0;-moz-transform-origin:0, 0;-o-transform-origin:0, 0;transform-origin:0, 0" viewBox="-220.38356461849224 6442.3347962008365 454.7376658611161 114.54981723871151"></svg>
```

Any other steps required to convert screen XY to SVG world XY apart from creating SVG point and applying transform?

**FYI:** SVG has viewBox set.

Comment: Browsers are buggy when you try to use CSS transforms. Here's the [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=972041)

Comment: @RobertLongson Is adding transform attribute suggested?

Comment: @RobertLongson Becase scale value is 1 and -1, the y coordinate value is taken from bottom. But not sure how to get correct calculation

Comment: Firefox would work correctly with a transform attribute. Chrome does not support a transform attribute on the svg element currently.